# Analong of Concurrency::combinable<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Is there any way of duplicating the functionality found within the combinable data structure within C++ in C#?

In C++ I could do something along the lines of:

```
Concurrency::combinable<CustomData> c;
Concurrency::parallel_for(0, size, [&](int i)
{
    CustomData cd = some_operation(i);
    c.local() += cd;
});
c.combine([](CustomData a, CustomData b) { return a + b; });
```

Where CustomData is some arbitrary data that has a well defined addition operator.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out PLINQ and the Aggregate method.  it's awesome.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460697.aspx